# How to validate in ASP.NET MVC properly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue to validate form in ASP.Net MVC. I have pasted `Views` and `Model` that I have used so that it will help you to find where I am doing wrong.

`View`

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(@Model.ActionName, "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" + Model.OrderID, enctype = "application/json" }))
{
    <h3 style="margin: 15px">@Model.DisplayName</h3>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.OrderID)

    <div>
        <div style="margin: 0px 0px 5px 20px; width:500px;">
            Month: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Month, new { title = "Value", style = "margin: 10px 40px 0 20px; width: 30px;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Month,"*")
            Year: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Year, new { title = "Value", style = "margin: 10px 40px 0 20px; width: 30px;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Year,"*")
            <button class="ui-button ui-button-report-text" style="margin: 0 0 0 40px" onclick="getOrder('form@(Model.OrderID)', '@Model.ActionName','order@(Model.OrderID)'); return false;">Get Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

`Model`

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public int Month { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public int Year { get; set; }
```

FYI, I am using `onclick` to submit my form.

TIA

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it not being validated in C# or in JavaScript?

Comment: Never mind.Just find out `[Required]` attribute doesn't work if we submit form through `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

we add a check

```
if($('form').valid()){
    //ajax call
}else{
    var $validator = $('form').validate();
    //show errors/validation
}
```

doing it this way the required attribute does work.  Hopefully this helps